# Get day from date return differences result?

Tags: java, calendar

If date param is 2015-08-08, in my country (timezone = +7) the day of the month will be 8 – exactly what i want. But in my partner's country (timezone = -8) the day of the month is 7.

Can anyone tell me why?

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date);
int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: Where and how did the "2015-08-08" get converted into a `Date` object?

Comment: I convert it to date from Json object

Answer (score 0):

[`Calendar#getInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance--) is using the default timezone, which is by default, your own.  Any changes that you see are reflected based on your local timezone.

If you want to change that, you can pass in `-Duser.timezone` as a parameter to your program to ensure that it starts in a specific timezone.

Comment: So there`s no way to make it auto recognize the timezone of the system that running the code?

Comment: The timezone of the system is the timezone that the system is set to.  If you have two machines set to two different timezones, then the program will be executed using two different timezone results.